# Set NaN values to Transparent in Matlab 'geoshow' function?

Tags: cartography, matlab, matlab-mapping-toolbox, plot

I am trying to plot rainfall values in MATLAB using `geoshow` function.
`NaN` values should be transparent in the map. However, the plot I am getting comes with dark blue color for `NaN` values. I have found that this is an issue in MATLAB.

Below is what I am trying;

```
geoshow(lat,lon,data, 'DisplayType', 'texturemap');
```

Where, **lat**, **lon**, and **data** are 2-dimensional matrices.
How to set `NaN` to transparent?

Comment: Sorry that I'm a bit late and probably no help to you anymore. But I think it's an well formulated and concise question that also might help others later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by [changing the alpha/transparency of an object:](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alpha.html)

```
[lat,lon]= meshgrid(0:10);% sample lat/lon
data = peaks(11); % sample data
data(:,2:3) = NaN; % some NaN values

geoimg = geoshow(lat,lon,data,'DisplayType', 'texturemap') % save object
geoimg.AlphaDataMapping = 'none'; % interpet alpha values as transparency values
geoimg.FaceAlpha = 'texturemap'; % Indicate that the transparency can be different each pixel
alpha(geoimg,double(~isnan(data))) % Change transparency to matrix where if data==NaN --> transparency = 1, else 0.
```

(requires Matlab 2015b or newer)

Comment: Its not working, and throwing error `Wrong number of arguments`

Comment: weird, it worked fine with my dummy data - what matlab version are you using? I presume `alpha()` is throwing the error?

Comment: @Mario Just to narrow down the error - does it also not work with the sample data I edited in?

Comment: I checked it with your sample data and edited code, it gives the same error. I ma using MATLAB 2013a

Comment: Ah, it's a version problem, this method was introduced in 2015b. With an older version it simply isn't possible to change the transparency. See https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=alpha&startrelease=R2013a&endrelease=R2015b&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=alpha